# Update database table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I am currently using grails and I am trying to figure out a way that I can update my database table `utility` with the two values selected from two drop down menus. My drop down menus are passed values from this table when a user selects a specific value from another drop down. I'm trying to figure out how to update my table so that I can load the newly changed values into the drop down menu upon reloading.

For example: I have `mondayStart` and `mondayEnd` drop down menus that are populated with times 9am-5pm based upon the values from the database. If the user changes the value from the drop down menu `mondayStart` from `9:00 am` to `10:00 am` the value `10:00:00` replaces the current database value `09:00:00` upon clicking the `Update` button I have created and will also update the other drop down menu `mondayEnd` upon being changed and will be overwritten in the database.

Currently I have my drop down menus which are populated from the users specific actions:

```
        <td style="text-align: center; width: 115px;" onchange="e" >
           <select name="mondayStart" id="mondayStart">

           </select>

           <select name="mondayEnd" id="mondayEnd">

           </select>
        </td>
```

And my test to see if the change alert is working:

```
    $("#mondayStart").live('change', function(e){

            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

This is my update button:

```
    <g:submitButton name="update" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px" type="button" id="update" value="Update" onchange="e" />
```

How can I set this up to allow my database to be updated with multiple values upon the click of my update button?

Comment: Post the action the form is hitting. What specifically isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I think something along these lines should do the trick :-

```
$("#update").click(function() {
    -- code for adding to the database would go here --
    -- might be an idea to use $.post() --
});
```

Let me know if this helps and if it doesn't I will try and come up with something else.

Comment: I understand that part actually, I'm more curious of how to replace the existing values with the currently selected values from the drop down menu. I don't know how to go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

You should submit the form (via ajax or normal way) and in your controller retrieve the values from params.

For example, you could have in your controller a method like the following:

```
def save(String mondayStart, String mondayEnd){
    //Update your domain with those values
    //render view, return values or redirect where you want
}
```

One note, you can define the parameters on the method parameters o just recover them from the `params` object